# Label of createBottomTabNavigator not showing - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I pulled one of my react native projects from a few months ago and While using it I discovered that `TabNavigator` was deprecated. So instread I am now using `createBottomTabNavigator` like they suggested. It seems to work out of the box, but for some reason my labels are not showing, only the icons in the tabs.

I was looking at the docs and it was saying it is actually default `true` for showing the label. For some reason the label just won't show up. Also tried to set the `showLabel` to true but that didn't do anything else. Someone with the same problem that got a fix?

My code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

// Icons for tabs
import I from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

// Navigation dep
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Custom components/screens
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import FavoritesScreen from './screens/FavoritesScreen'
import AccountScreen from './screens/AccountScreen'

// Custom styles
import HeaderBar from './styles/HeaderBar'

// Tabs navigation
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen
});

const FavoritesStack = createStackNavigator({
    Favorites: FavoritesScreen
});

const AccountStack = createStackNavigator({
    Account: AccountScreen
});

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeStack,
        Favorites: FavoritesStack,
        Account: AccountStack,
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {

                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let iconName;
                if (routeName === 'Home') {
                    iconName = `tag${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                } else if (routeName === 'Favorites') {
                    iconName = `heart${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                } else {
                    iconName = `account-box${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                }

                return <I name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
            },
            tabBarLabel: () => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                return routeName.toUpperCase();

            }
        }),

        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#E95736',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 9,
                fontFamily: 'Rubik-Medium'
            },
            style: {
                backgroundColor: '#FAF8F8',
                borderTopWidth: 0.5
            },
        },
    }
```

);

Comment: does it work if you remove the `tabBarLabel` bit of the navigation options?

Comment: @NoahAllen Yes! Worked out. Already found that out yesterday but found it quite weird to answer my own question. If you can answer this question with some more details I can accept it as the answer for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is related to `tabBarLabel` and I believe the problem will fix itself if you remove that bit. You can easily achieve the same effect by just making the label text upper case where you declare the route.